# Web Scraping with Beautiful soup multiple duplicate tags

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

This is my first time web scraping and am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng2o98k983k). I am using this [website](https://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/ORxmasnw.php) to scrape information from. I am trying to grab the text that reads "89426 Green Mountain Road, Astoria, OR 97103. Phone: 503-325-9720." I noticed that I have multiple `ul` and `li` tags within my `div class_=alert` tag. So I am not sure how to grab a specific one. Here is what I have tried, but continue to get a different text from another group of `ul`/`li`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/ORxmasnw.php').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

noble_ridge = soup.find('div', class_='alert')
information = noble_ridge.ul.li.text
print(information)
# print(soup.prettify())


C:\Users\name\anaconda3\envs\Scraping\python.exe C:/Users/name/PycharmProjects/Scraping/Christmas_tree_farms.py
If the name of the farm is blue with an underline; that's a link to their website. Click on it for the most current hours and information.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: hi there - good day dear Zman3 - many thanks for picking up the Scraper of Curey Schafer. Awesome - just very awesome. Keep um the great work - it rocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.select_one("span.farm")
    goal = list(target.next_elements)[5].rsplit(" ", 2)[0]
    print(goal)


main("https://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/ORxmasnw.php")
```

Output:

```
89426 Green Mountain Road, Astoria, OR 97103. Phone: 503-325-9720.
```

Using `re`:

```py
import requests
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = [item.group(1) for item in re.finditer(r'>(\d.+\d{4})\.', r.text)]
    print(match[0])


main("https://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/ORxmasnw.php")
```

Output:

```
89426 Green Mountain Road, Astoria, OR 97103. Phone: 503-325-9720
```

Comment: Sorry, but I am having some issues with yours and was looking for something more like @atinjanki. I'd like to keep it close to the tutorial since I am new at this.

Comment: @Zman3 which issues you have? I've ran both codes and there's no issues on my end.

Comment: Hmmm, must have typed something incorrectly. That works. I am a little confused with how this is running and how I can modify it. Do you mind if we chat in a room?

Comment: @Zman3 https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212113/python-scraping

Answer (score 2):

**noble_ridge** has many **ul** tags inside it.

Using

> noble_ridge.ul

takes you to the first **ul** tag found. See the image below -

[image]

And your expected text - **"89426 Green Mountain Road, Astoria, OR 97103. Phone: 503-325-9720"** is under the next ul tag.

Hence, if you wish to directly traverse there, you could use -

```
noble_ridge.findAll('ul')[1].li.text
```

Or you could loop through all tags and look for your text like -

```
source = requests.get('https://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/ORxmasnw.php').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

noble_ridge = soup.find('div', class_='alert')

ultags =  noble_ridge.findAll('ul')

temp = '89426 Green Mountain Road, Astoria, OR 97103. Phone: 503-325-9720'

for tag in ultags:
    litags =  tag.findAll('li')
    #print(litags)
    for li in litags:
        tx = li.getText()
        #print(tx)
        if tx.find(temp)>-1:

            print(tag)
```

This will get you the **ul** tag which has the text.

Comment: Could you please explain what is going on with the `-1`?

Comment: @Zman3 *tx.find(temp)* is finding temp(substring) inside tx.  *find()* function returns -1 when the specified substring is not found. Read more here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you!